# PHP displaying page views for gallery style pages

Tags: php, google-analytics, view

This is really a point me in the right direction question. What path should I take if I want to display the number of page views each gallery page receives?

1. Retrieve Google Analytics Data via PHP, or
2. Capture the page views directly on my pages with my own PHP and mySQL setup?

Seems, like number 1 would be the better choice. I just don't know how difficult this option will be. Any insights on this?

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is definitely simpler.

If you do figure out how to get the page results out of Google Analytics, they will not be up-to-date. It takes Google at least several hours before the page views show up.

Answer (score 0):

That also depends if You want to have info on more questions (statistics). I often use custom setup to track such things cause I can later use some data to do statistics about users actions. 
For example, You want to give users (owners of photos) info about witch users (male or female, 30+ or below 30, and so on) are viewing. How many guests, how many registered users. There are tons of data You can retrive by building custom system.
It all depends on what You want to have at the end.
I suspect that if You want to have only raw data about number of users You coud somehow parse data from Google Analytics as well.

And as posted below. Google have to take time to update, custom setup not.